# Story about a soldier promising to go to yeshiva

Tags: story-identification, rav-shlomo-z-auerbach

I remember hearing a story about Shlomo Zalman Auerbach with a soldier who had a near death experience and promised Hashem that if he was saved he would go to yeshivah, but since he waited a couple of days he never ended up being able to go to yeshivah for whatever reason. I don’t remember how the story goes fully, if anyone could help that would be great it’s very important. Thanks.

Comment: VTC as it's not about Judaism it's about a story of a Jewish person

Comment: @ezra I’m sorry if this is out of place, it’s just very important that I find this story. Further I would respectfully disagree as Rashi famously says יָפָה שִׂיחָתָן שֶׁל עַבְדֵי אָבוֹת לִפְנֵי הַמָּקוֹם מִתּוֹרָתָן שֶׁל בָּנִים, I think we as a religion are largely defined by the stories of our gedolim.

Comment: I don't disagree with you or Rashi, just based on my reading of the Site Rules this question seems to be off-topic.

Comment: @ezra Davening to Hashem, making nedarim (perhaps), and going to yeshiva are all expressions of Judaism. Therefore, this would be a story about Judaism and therefore on-topic.